# iPhone turning off on 10 - 20% and battery percentage not showing right

Tags: iphone, battery

I have an iPhone 5s running iOS 11.0.3. When it's down to about 15%, it dies completely.
Can I do something about that?

Also, when It's at around 15% and I plug the iPhone into the power supply, it often goes up to 25% instantly.
Why is my iPhone doing that?

Comment: You need a new battery.  These are all the classic signs that the battery inside your phone is nearing end of life.  Since it's older, I'd check with 3rd party shops, it's often easier to find them by searching for glass repair, but if they do glass repairs they will also change batteries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Tyson, these are classic "dead battery" symptoms. If you want to be certain before ordering a replacement battery or having it repaired, use a battery utility, such as [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) (for Mac) or [3uTools](http://www.3u.com/) (for Windows). It will tell you what the health of the battery is (Design Capacity). If your battery shows anything less than 70% of design capacity, it will require replacement.

Comment: 71% isn't good neither, is it?

Comment: 71% is still usable but the battery's not going to get any better ;>). When the design capacity drops in the 50-60 range, the phone starts shutting down unexpectedly.